# Bounty question can't be close voted?

Tags: support, flags, bounty

I came across a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221413/what-tools-are-available-for-documenting-javascript that perfectly fits one of the close vote categories. I'm not 100% sure it should be closed as it seems to have some decent attention but I thought I'd flag to the community.

I however don't seem to be able to close vote it as it has a bounty and flagging uses the same mechanism. Should I be able to close for this really? If not how should I deal with this?

Comment: I can cast close votes and flags just fine. At least it seems that way to me, I haven't actually tried it, just clicked on the close and flag links.

Comment: Yep, bountied questions can not be closed as long as the bounty is open. I find it weird that a 10k user opened a bounty for that, since the question is clearly offtopic by todays standards. But maybe it should get a historical lock like the definitive book lists etc.

Comment: @JustSid: Try actually trying to close the question; you get a window that says that the question has an open bounty and cannot be closed.

Comment: @KenWhite Ah, thanks! I was wondering, hence the comment.

Comment: Maybe you should've added a bounty to this question... ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, questions with open bounties can't be closed.

I've run into this issue before. I post a custom flag, and indicate that it's a bounty-protected off-topic question that can't be closed by normal means, and ask a mod to refund the bounty and allow closure. I've had about 50% success rate doing so.